# JS code stopped executing when file dialog open

Tags: javascript, html, input

When I try open file dialog (input type=file) my JS code stopped executing in IE. Could you explain me why it happend? And how I can fix it?

JS:

```
    function Count() { 
    num++;
    document.timerform.clock.value = num;
    down = setTimeout("Count()", 1000);
    }
    function timeIt() {
    num=0;
    Count();
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <BODY OnLoad="timeIt()">
    <center>   
    <form name="timerform">
    <input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="1:00"><p>
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    </form>
    </center>
```

version vith iframe:

```
    <BODY OnLoad="timeIt()">
    <center>
    <form name="timerform">
    <input type="text" name="clock" size="7" value="1:00"><p>
    <iframe src="blank.html" height="200" width="500">My frame.</iframe>
    </form>
    </center>
```

blank.html:

```
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the nature of the browser. There's nothing you can do about it. (aside from putting the file dialog in an Iframe)

Comment: Do you mean that everything will just stop (hang) when file dialogue box will open and is it same for every browser ?

Comment: Tested it on Firefox and the counter keeps going. You can try it here on other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/gq7ut/

Comment: Worked on chrome 16.0.912.77 and ff 10.0 and also opera but didn't worked on ie8. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, it works on any browsers, except IE. But I need it work on IE

Comment: OK, write to Microsoft. There is nothing you can do in JavaScript to change this. Considering using an Iframe. It's your only hope.

Comment: I tried putting the file dialog in an Iframe before, but it's doesn't work.

Comment: The clock still runs - you can compare the start and end time of when the dialog was opened.

Comment: What do you need to accomplish?

Comment: I need executing my script when file dialog is open

Comment: For what purpose?!?!!?!? Perhaps there is another way to tackle this problem because this will NEVER work as it is.

Comment: I have application in which executing more complex JS than in this examples (update session in WEB application), but when users open file dialog, this JS just stop and users session timeout

Comment: @saltex I am facing a similar issue while designing a website. Have you found any workaround that migh help..

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded.  If you want a second counter to use `setTimeout` and not get way off because of javascript I suggest you use the Date object.  Do the following:

```
var startTime = 0;
function Count() { 
    document.timerform.clock.value = Math.round((new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000);
    down = setTimeout(Count, 1000);
}
function timeIt() {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    Count();
}
```

Then even if you have an event that takes control of the javascript thread you won't get off count once the count picks back up.  You still want to avoid those situations, but don't ever count on setTimeout to be the exact time you set it to be.

Comment: I see. Yes it's useful notice. But even this script stop when file dialog open (document.timerform.clock.value - doesn't updated). My goal to receive the same behavior as in FF or Chrome if it possible